# Browse an UNC path using Windows CMD without mapping it to a network drive

Tags: windows, command-line, network-drive, unc

```
C:\> cd \\somewhere
'\\somewhere'
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

What I usually do to get around this is to map that directory to a network drive and then I could easily access it from the command prompt.

But is there an easier way on how to get around this?

Comment: which windows do you use? If it's Windows 7, you've powershell preinstalled on your system. Powershell supports unc-paths and cmd-commands (with few exceptions).

Comment: You can always browse to the unc path through run.

Comment: @wullxz: cheers, I didn't know you could browse UNC paths with PowerShell.

@kyle: That's actually a valid answer according to my question :)  But I want to access it from a command line environment.  Will modify my question to make this more clear.

Comment: If your problem is that you need to work just from the command line, you can map the network drive with the 'net' command:  net use x: \\computer name\share name

Comment: @Aleister Crowley: Yes I know, but I'm asking if there's an easier way that doesn't involve mapping a network drive.

Comment: @Andreas Grech: I thought that was likely the case, that's why I put it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Use powershell and it works

Comment: Related: [How do you handle “CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories”?](https://serverfault.com/q/50085/4276) from Server Fault

Comment: @wullxz That deserves to be an answer. Look at the answers below; "ContextConsole Shell Extension" and "Git Bash" get several upvotes. I think PowerShell is better than third-party solutions.

Comment: @FranklinYu added the answer

Comment: If you mean to browse in Windows explorer you can start an Explorer instance pointed at the desired drive with:
start \\servername\sharedpath

Answer (score 299, accepted):

If you use [`pushd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490978(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [`popd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490969(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead of `cd` you won't get that UNC error.

`pushd <UNC path>` will create a temporary virtual drive and get into it.
`popd` will delete the temporary drive and get you back to the path you were when you entered `pushd`.

Example:

```
C:\a\local\path> pushd \\network_host\a\network\path

U:\a\network\path> REM a temporary U: virtual drive has been created

U:\a\network\path> popd

C:\a\local\path> REM the U: drive has been deleted

C:\a\local\path>
```

Comment: Using `pushd` creates a drive mapping to the network share and then changes into a path relative to the share it creates. `popd` disconnects the share.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 10. `C:\WINDOWS\system32>pushd \\some\network\path`

`' '
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`

Comment: It's just worked for me in Windows 10, how odd.  I did `pushd \\ServerName\home\dir\dir2`.

Comment: Native and elegant, just a wonder. Works for Windows 10.

Comment: Is there any trick to make it work when the share credentials don't match the machine's user credentials?

Comment: works perfect. and I need check how to put these kind of directory into perl script.

Comment: @Perkins: I was able to use runas.exe to run PowerShell as the other user

Comment: @JacobKrall That would work if another user has the proper credentials.  If it's a totally different set of credentials, use cmdkey.

Comment: Works perfect. I was using the sshfs, if it will automatically create a virtual drive (Z, in my case). And access normally to Z like the ones did in C or D.

Comment: I also noticed that if you pushd to the same location it will map a new network drive again and again and if you close the shell and open a new one calling popd will not, of course, be able to unmap them so one could end up having a bunch of unused network drives.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I receive that same error once every available drive letter has been reserved. I used PUSHD on the same folder several times and filled "This PC" with letters B & D-Z. (C was my local drive but I don't know what A was. Possibly, it's a hidden partition but I couldn't find it.) The next time I tried to exact command that had just worked 15 times in a row, I got the same error you posted: `' ' CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks for the heads up! Very possible that was the problem for me.

Answer (score 24):

I use [Git Bash](https://msysgit.github.io/) to do this, since I already have it installed. As an added bonus, it also has better colors, lets me use `ls`, `rm`, etc., and uses the correct slash for paths.

[image]

Comment: You can also use backslashes if you escape them with backslashes: `cd \\\\server\\share\\subdirectory`

Comment: Also, if you try to use tab completion with computer names, the shell might lock up for some time until the names are resolved.

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: Although Git Bash worked for me, it seemed slower than pushd/popd and CMD as used in [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/399885/918268) for some reason. Though I also prefer Git Bash in general, and use it instead of CMD wherever possible.

Answer (score 13):

Kliu's "ContextConsole Shell Extension" (aka Open Command Prompt) says it, "can even open directories from network paths (UNC paths)" (from an Explorer window).

http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/

[image]

Comment: This program is most awesome!

Comment: i'm shocked by the screenshot, it exist!

Comment: remember to open the //drive and not a mapped version.
It will fail on mapped.

Answer (score 12):

I also hit the UNC problem with `C:\> cd \\somewhere` in a C program.  Found this page and learnt about the `net` command: `net use x: \\computer name\share name` and used it successfully!  Thanks to all who post their experiences for others to learn from.  :-)

Comment: Yes, but using `net use` will map that location to a network drive and that is not what I wanted.

Comment: @AndreasGrech, Actually `pushd` does that too.

Comment: This works well in `Far`+`ConEmu`, unlike `pushd`.

Comment: @Pacerier But `pushd` automatically selects a drive letter and disconnects the network drive when it’s no longer needed (after `popd` or `exit`).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using XP you can have a look at this site https://web.archive.org/web/20150518102450/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156276

(In case the link breaks again: Under `Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`: add a DWORD value called `DisableUNCCheck` if it doesn’t already exist and set it to `1`.)

There is a registry value that you need to add, log out, log in again ... and now your cmd.exe does support UNC-Paths. It seems to me that you still can't cd to the path, but you can use it in other commands like dir, copy ...

An alternative might be using the pushd command, that will let you switch to the share (i guess by assigning it a temporary drive letter) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd

Comment: The pages you linked seem like empty pages......

Comment: The links work here. Have you tried using https?

Comment: Seems to still work under windows 10 20H2

Answer (score -2):

imho, the most elegant solution is to use mklink /D to create a symlink for the network path. if you use in a script you'll not have to find out which drive letter has been assigned.

Comment: The most elegant way to change directories (a read-only operation) is to modify the filesystem?  And where do you create the link?  `\Temp`?  You might not have write access to the current directory.  And what do you call the link?  What if there’s already a `\Temp\somewhere` that isn’t already a link to `\\somewhere`?  What if it’s a file that’s in use?  Etc…  How is this more elegant than `pushd`?

Answer (score -4):

You can use the HttpFileServer application, it' over windows, very light and very easy to configure , it allow you to share a network folder UNC ( \server\share ) with HTTP protocol and the HTTP link can be used in any HTML page

http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/

it's amazing

Comment: Not very useful to a command line user.

Comment: I agree that this is an amazing piece of software, but how can it be used to get around the fact that the CMD window app does not handler UNC?